# How can I redirect user to a home page after logged out?

Tags: blazor

This doesn't redirect me :( I can see:
[image]

```
@page "/authentication/{action}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication

<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" OnLogOutSucceeded="LogOutSucceededHandler">
</RemoteAuthenticatorView>

@code{
    [Parameter] public string? Action { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }

    public void LogOutSucceededHandler()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
    }

}
```

I don't know why :( I don't know what I can write more.

Comment: Have you tried to force load? NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/", true);

Comment: Then firstly I can see "You are logged out" for 1 seconds, and then the home page. :O

Comment: @enet, Can we apply your solution with `auth microsoft 365`?

Answer (score 1):

I've stumbled upon the similar issue. In my case, I wanted to redirect users to different pages after the successful log in. I've used `NavigationManager.NavigateTo` method within the `OnLogInSucceeded` event callback, which led to the same result as yours.

I found two ways how to achieve the correct redirect behavior.

The **first** one is to use the method overload which allows force reload: `NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/", true);`. Even though the goal is achieved, the whole app is reloaded like when F5 hotkey was pressed.

The **second** one is to implement an `IDisposable` interface. I prefer this one much more as it just smoothly redirects to the correct page. Here is an example:

```
@page "/authentication/{action}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;
@implements IDisposable

<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" />

@code {

    [Parameter] public string? Action { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An other alternative more simple, just call the `NavigationManager.NavigateToLogout()` extension method on the button who perform the logout action, and specify the `./` for the redirect URL.

For example:

```
<button @onclick="this.Logout">Logout</button>

@code{
    [Inject]
    public NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }

    public void Logout()
    {
        this.NavigationManager.NavigateToLogout("./authentication/logout", "./");
    }
}
```